# Use background-image: url() in .scss file with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

I'm trying to use `background-image: url('../assests/logo.png)` in .scss file.To resolve the url of the file I used [resolve-url-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader).  And
This is how my project structure is:

```
project-root/
├── src/
│   ├── contentscript/
│   │   └── contentscript.scss
├── assets/
│   └── images/
│       └── background.jpg
```

But still I get the below error:

```
    ERROR in ./src/contentscript/contentscript.scss
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
    ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are         configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

And this is how I use background image in .scss file

```
    .my-element {
     background-image: url('../assets/images/background.jpg');
     /* Other styles... */
    }
```

This is how configured my webpack.config.js file

```
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', {
          loader: 'resolve-url-loader'
        }, {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
          }
        }],
      },
```

Comment: Based on the error, I can see that you don't have a loader for for the `jpg` file types.
Add the file type to the `test` rule. Something like `test: /\.(scss|jpg)$/`.

Otherwise try a separate loader for image files, so that Webpack knows what to do with `.jpg` file types.